# How do I flip (reflect/mirror) an image on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I already have an image displayed on a tkinter `Canvas` using the `Canvas.create_image()` method.

I want to now flip the image *after* calling the `create_image()` method. I have the ID of the canvas object and also the filepath of the original image. So I want the existing canvas image to be replaced with a horizontally mirrored image.

I also want this to be something that can happen an unknown but unlimited number of times in my program, so just getting a PIL Image from the filepath and flipping that image and destroying and redrawing the image wouldn't work because the file itself always stays facing the same direction so after getting flipped once it would never go back to its original state. And also that just seems a bit cumbersome to read the disk every time I want to flip the image; surely it's possible to do it just in memory?

What's the best way of doing this?

Tagging with PIL because I thought PIL might be helpful for doing this, but obviously if it's not necessary to do this then it's not relevant.

Also, my program should be able to run in an environment with only Python standard libraries and possibly PIL if needed, so unfortunately I can't install anything with pip.

Comment: "And also that just seems a bit cumbersome to read the disk every time I want to flip the image; surely it's possible to do it just in memory?" - This is backwards-think. Why do you want to fill up the memory with numerous versions of an image when you can get it "on-the-fly" from disk? Also, you don't have to do any of that. You can just keep flipping the same image.

Comment: PIL images do support a transpose() method.

Comment: @OysterShucker Why would you need to fill up the memory with numerous versions of an image? I don't need to hold on to "previous" versions of it. As for "you can just keep flipping the same image", yes, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: It is better to post what you have tried on *"flipping the same image"* so that we can know why it is not working.

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. If you have `ID` then you can use it to replace image using `canvas.itemconfig(ID, )`. And you don't have to destroy original `PhotoImage` - and you can use it again without reading file again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I don't know what is the problem.

If you have `item_id` then you can replace image with

```
canvas.itemconfig(item_id, image=tk_flipped_image)
```

Of course it always needs to use `PIL` to flip image.

And if you want to flip the same image many times then you don't have to destroy it.
Keep both versions in memory.

---

Full Working code.

I use `after()` to replace image every 1000ms (1s)

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

# --- functions ---

def update_image():
    global index 
    
    index = (index + 1) % 2

    if index == 0:
        canvas.itemconfig(image_id, image=tk_image_0)
    else:
        canvas.itemconfig(image_id, image=tk_image_1)
    
    root.after(1000, update_image)  # run again after 1000ms
    
# --- main ---
    
root = tk.Tk()

pil_image_0 = Image.open("test.png")
pil_image_1 = pil_image_0.transpose(Image.FLIP_TOP_BOTTOM)   # Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT

tk_image_0 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image_0)
tk_image_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image_1)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=pil_image_0.width, height=pil_image_0.height)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

index = 0
image_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=tk_image_0, anchor='nw')

root.after(1000, update_image)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `PIL`, it has support for a `transpose()` method that can be be used to mirror images.

```py
import tkinter
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')

pil_image = Image.open("test.png")
pil_image = pil_image.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)

tk_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pil_image)
canvas.create_image(100, 100, image=tk_image, anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I've said, I want to flip the image *after* I've already used `create_image`, and replace the existing image with the flipped image, and possibly do this unlimited times. I know I can flip PIL images, but what's the best way to do it to an existing image object on a canvas?

Comment: Don't you want to `delete()` the image from the canvas and ew-create it from you PIL manipulation?

Comment: @revsuine I think the best way is `canvas.itemconfig(ID, image=tk_flipped_image)` but first you have to use `PIL` to flip original image (like in answer above). And you don't have to destroy and read file again.